# Can't select a checkbox with jQuery

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have this HTML

```
<label class="">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="selectAll" name="RAT_RoomsAffected">
        Activate
    </label>
</label> 

<br />

<label class="">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="RAT_RoomsList[]" value="75" checked="">
        <div style="width: 200px">Room #1</div>
    </label>
</label>

<label class="">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="RAT_RoomsList[]" value="76" checked="">
        <div style="width: 200px">Room #2</div>
    </label>
</label>
```

And here's my try:

```
if($('.selectAll').length) {
    $('.selectAll').click(function() {
        if ($(this).prop("checked", true)) {
            $('input[type=checkbox]').not('.selectAll').each(function() {
                this.checked = false;
            });
        }
    });
    $('input[type=checkbox]').not('.selectAll').click(function() {
        if ($(this).prop("checked", true)) {
            $('.selectAll').prop("checked", false);
        }
    });
}
```

Actually, my problem is I can't click on the `Room #1` and `Room #2` checkboxes.

I think I'm very near of the solution but I can't make it work actually.

Do you know why please ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are actually *setting* the checked property in your `if` ... not *getting* it.

When setting; it will return jQuery object which is always truthy. When getting; it returns boolean

The logic in the second condition is backwards.

It should uncheck selectAll if the other one us unchecked, not checked

```js
$('.selectAll').click(function() {
  if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
    $('input[type=checkbox]').not(this).prop("checked", true);
  }
});
$('input[type=checkbox]').not('.selectAll').click(function() {
  if (!$(this).prop("checked")) {
    $('.selectAll').prop("checked", false);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="selectAll" name="RAT_RoomsAffected">
        Activate
    </label>
</label>

<br />

<label class="">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="RAT_RoomsList[]" value="75" checked="">
        <div style="width: 200px">Room #1</div>
    </label>
</label>

<label class="">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="RAT_RoomsList[]" value="76" checked="">
        <div style="width: 200px">Room #2</div>
    </label>
</label>
```

Comment: Hello, look working but how can I uncheck other checkboxes when 'Activate' is checked please? Thanks.

Comment: Oh...you want Activate to uncheck the others? I assumed that since it was "selectAll" you wanted to have them all checked

Comment: Yes please. Thanks.

Comment: Change `true` to `false`